# Ordering within a MySQL group

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are joined - one holds schedules and the other holds actual worked times.

This works fine if a given user only has a single schedule on a day but when they have more than one schedule I cannot get the query to match up the "right" slot to the right time.

I am beginning to think the only way to do this is to allocate the time to the schedule when the clock event happens but that is going to be a big rewrite so I am hoping there is a way in MySQL.

As this is inside a third party application, I am limited in what I can do to the query - I can modify the basics like from, group, joins etc and I can add aggregates to the fields (I have toyed with using min/max on the times). However, if the only way is to write a hugely complex query especially within the field selections then this system simply doesn't give me that option.

Schedule table:

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `schedule`
--

INSERT INTO `schedule` (`id`, `user_id`, `date`, `start_time`, `end_time`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2019-07-07', '08:00:00', '12:00:00'),
(2, 1, '2019-07-07', '16:00:00', '22:00:00'),
(3, 1, '2019-07-06', '10:00:00', '18:00:00');
```

Time table

```
CREATE TABLE `time` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `time`
--

INSERT INTO `time` (`id`, `user_id`, `date`, `start_time`, `end_time`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2019-07-07', '08:00:00', '12:00:00'),
(2, 1, '2019-07-07', '16:00:00', '22:00:00'),
(3, 1, '2019-07-06', '10:00:00', '18:00:00');
```

Current query

```
select 
t.date as date, t.user_id, 
s.start_time as schedule_start, 
s.end_time as schedule_end, 
t.start_time as actual_start, 
t.end_time as actual_end 
from time t 
left join schedule s on 
t.user_id=s.user_id and t.date=s.date 
group by t.date, t.start_time
```

Current output

```
== Dumping data for table s

|2019-07-06|1|10:00:00|18:00:00|10:00:00|18:00:00
|2019-07-07|1|08:00:00|12:00:00|08:00:00|12:00:00
|2019-07-07|1|08:00:00|12:00:00|16:00:00|22:00:00
```

Desired output

```
== Dumping data for table s

|2019-07-06|1|10:00:00|18:00:00|10:00:00|18:00:00
|2019-07-07|1|08:00:00|12:00:00|08:00:00|12:00:00
|2019-07-07|1|16:00:00|22:00:00|16:00:00|22:00:00
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: You select columns that don't exist in the `group by` clause and they're not aggregated, so the results you get do not make sense. Also you don't mention the logic for the results you want.

Comment: The logic is so the end user can see what time a user clocked in/out against their expected scheduled time and see gaps where someone didn't, for example

Comment: The sample data you posted contain rows for only 1 user and 2 rows for the same date for the same user. Also the times are identical in both tables

Comment: That is by design - I am only showing one user but in the case of 7/7, the user was meant to clock in at 8 and clock out at 12 which he did and was then meant to clock in at 4 and clock out a 10 which he did. However, in the actual output you cannot see that hence my question

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this.
I selected 15 min time limit that a shift should start

```
select 
  t.date as date, t.user_id, 
  s.start_time as schedule_start, 
  s.end_time as schedule_end, 
  t.start_time as actual_start, 
  t.end_time as actual_end 
from time t 
  left join schedule s on 
  t.user_id=s.user_id and t.date=s.date 
  and s.start_time  BETWEEN t.start_time - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE 
  AND  t.start_time + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
 order by date,schedule_start;
```

Grouping would you do be add up time for every day and user day

Comment: That's a really interesting idea that had not even crossed my mind! I am going to have a play around with this

Answer (score 1):

You need a much more complicated query to distinguish the 2 shifts.
So you must execute 2 separate queries each for each shift and combine them with UNION:

```
select
  s.date, s.user_id,
  s.schedule_start, 
  s.schedule_end, 
  t.actual_start, 
  t.actual_end   
from (
  select s.date, s.user_id, 
    min(s.start_time) as schedule_start, 
    min(s.end_time) as schedule_end
  from schedule s
  group by s.date, s.user_id
) s left join (
  select t.date, t.user_id,
    min(t.start_time) as actual_start, 
    min(t.end_time) as actual_end
  from time t
  group by t.date, t.user_id
) t on t.user_id=s.user_id and t.date=s.date 
union
select
  s.date, s.user_id,
  s.schedule_start, 
  s.schedule_end, 
  t.actual_start, 
  t.actual_end   
from (
  select s.date, s.user_id, 
    max(s.start_time) as schedule_start, 
    max(s.end_time) as schedule_end
  from schedule s
  group by s.date, s.user_id
) s left join (
  select t.date, t.user_id,
    max(t.start_time) as actual_start, 
    max(t.end_time) as actual_end
  from time t 
  group by t.date, t.user_id
) t on t.user_id=s.user_id and t.date=s.date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=86f87dae5f6f7dbf50a973cbd933555b).
Results:

```
> date       | user_id | schedule_start | schedule_end | actual_start | actual_end
> :--------- | ------: | :------------- | :----------- | :----------- | :---------
> 2019-07-06 |       1 | 10:00:00       | 18:00:00     | 10:00:00     | 18:00:00  
> 2019-07-07 |       1 | 08:00:00       | 12:00:00     | 08:00:00     | 12:00:00  
> 2019-07-07 |       1 | 16:00:00       | 22:00:00     | 16:00:00     | 22:00:00
```

Comment: What if there is 3 shifts or more? It is unlikely I accept but would this still work?

Comment: 3 shifts or more in a date for a user? Is this possible? If it is then no, this code will not work.

Comment: It is not likely it will happen but we didn't anticipate more than one shift per day either!

Comment: This query will work for the case of maximum 2 shifts per date/user and there must exist the same number of rows per date/user in both tables. So if there are 2 shifts for a user for some day in schedule, there must also exist 2 rows in time table.

Comment: A suggestion: add a column to both tables indicating the shift (1, 2, 3, ..). Then everything will be easier and all you need is a join.